# ColdFusion ... doing a CFHTTP call inside a CFLOOP

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

Okay so this is lame but I have a file/ftp server that serves the assets for my web application. The client set up the ftp server before I started the application.

So it works fine when I just show images in my app. Even though it is cross domain. Now the client wants me to be able to take all of the assets for each test and bundle it up in a zip file. Oh and they won't upgrade so we are using CF7!!

So okay I make a list of the images and then I loop over it and do the cfhttp call inside the loop. Write the image to a temp directory I set up and then zip the whole damn thing up. It works except for the cfhttp call. I get the first image and then nothing.

```
<cfset imageList = "image_01.png,image_02.png" />   

<cfloop index="strImage" list="#imageList#" delimiters=",">
    <cfhttp method="GET" url="#theImgPath##strImage#" path="#TempPath##OSdelim#images" result="objGet" />
</cfloop>
```

The first image shows up on the server the second one does not.

Any idea if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: To troubleshoot, switch the order of your images to see if you now get the other one.

Comment: I'll see if I can do that. The list is actually generated by parsing xml data. Some really fugly code. :) Parse a bunch of crap and then do a list append. Someone said to make sure I do a trim() before I pass it to cfhttp so I'm gonna try that as well. It's funky though if I dump the objGet result right after the cfhttp call I get data after every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Since you are loading imageList from XML, try <cfoutput> ing the list before running the loop to verify that it has what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something like:

```
<!--- Lose the forward slash at the end, CF isn't XHTML --->
<cfset imageList = "image_01.png,image_02.png">   

<cfloop index="strImage" list="#imageList#" delimiters=",">
    <cfset fileName = strImage>
    <cfif not fileExists(TempPath & OSdelim & "images" & OSdelim & strImage)>
        <cfhttp method="get" getAsBinary="yes" url="#theImgPath##strImage#" path="#TempPath##OSdelim#images" file="#localfile#">
        downloading... <br />
    <cfelse>
        <cfoutput>#TempPath# #OSdelim# images #strImage# already exists</cfoutput><br />
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

The code is untested, but I reckon it should work, or at least give you a good grasp of where you're going wrong with the paths (in case you are)

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think the path is an issue. I get one file so the path to where to store the image on the server is correct.

Comment: I did! For some reason the docs said not to use  file="#localfile#" because the file would be named whatever came off of the request ... well this was the issue. So I added  file="#strImage#" and it worked so thank you very much!!